# storing media in databases vs other options

Tags: database-design

I am looking for advice as to the most optimal way to store and retrieve media files such as mp3 files, etc.

Does anyone here have experience with this type of problem?

I'm just looking for suggestions as to how to approach this particular problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given any context to your question so I'll assume a CMS web based application of some kind as this is most common.

The method most often used for media is to store the media files on disk and put only the meta data and a file id of some kind in the database.  This makes managing the database simpler (it will be a tiny fraction of the size it would otherwise be) and serving the files is simpler and faster (esp. for larger files).  The downside to this approach is that files are often less secure and it is also very difficult to ensure that the file store and database backups are in sync.

We have a VLE system that stores its media locally and has an Oracle backend to store other data.  After a few years of use, the database has grown to 40Gb plus backups and log etc but the file store is now close to 2Tb.  As the DBA I'm pretty happy about that choice.  Although I can do full point-in-time recovery of the database at any point I'm am not sure that is true of the media files.  2Tb of SATA (file store) SAN vs 2Tb+ of Fibre Channel (database) SAN also saves money (remember that +.  It can add up:  For Oracle this means more redo, temp, RMAN backups etc).

We also have a small CMS that handles the corporate type pages on the main website.  This puts (most of) its media into the database.  This serves a few hundred pages and has a 35Gb Oracle database.  It is clever enough to cache everything so it doesn't need to fish about inside the database for stuff all the time.  All the data for this vital application is in one fairly secure place.  As the DBA I'm pretty happy with that too.  Although in this case the CMS does has a few quirks with revisioning that sometimes have resulted it a new copy of almost all the data for a simple change.  This is much harder to manage in the database (redo, undo, space recovery etc).

There is always a trade off in choosing the location.  Space in the database is more expensive, but can be a good choice if your application justifies it.  What is "best" depends a lot on what you are doing and how you feel about the importance, security, cost and speed of your application and its contents.  You also need to consider the overheads of managing and supporting a large database - many DBA process have issues scaling.  What you do with large file systems isn't much different to a small one.  That just isn't so true in database.  At the 40Gb level we enjoy a nightly backup in RMAN, with three days online, a nightly consistent datapump export with 5 days online, and 24 hours of flashback.  Those are all very nice but at 2Tb we just could not have them.

I've given an Oracle perspective on this, but much of it applies to other databases too.